# MS SQL query within a query ColdFusion environment

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have 2 tables, one is called Food while the other is FoodCategory. The relation between them is the FoodCatID which contain in both tables.

What I try to archive is displaying:

### Meat

- Chicken
- Beef

### Veg

- tomatoe
- potatoe

I assume I will need a query within a query?  I first try to use Distinct to get the 2 unique FoodCatID:

```
Select Distinct FoodCategory.FoodCatID, FoodCategoryName
From Food INNER JOIN FoodCategory ON Food.FoodCatID = FoodCategory.FoodCatID
```

This will give me the 2 categories, but then how can I use the CatID to run the second part of the query?

I'm using this on a ColdFusion page, should I archive the result using SQL queries or can I do it through CF code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I archive the result using SQL queries or can I do it through
>   CF code?

Both. Use a single JOIN to retrieve the categories and food names. **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fe34/1/0)**

```
SELECT fc.FoodCatID
       , fc.FoodCategoryName
       , f.FoodID
       , f.FoodName
FROM   FoodCategory fc INNER JOIN Food f ON f.FoodCatID = fc.FoodCatID
ORDER BY fc.FoodCategoryName, f.FoodName
```

Then use a "grouped" [cfoutput](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff6.html). to list all of the foods - but only display the category headers once.

*Note, the results **must** be ordered by category name first, or it will not work*

```
  <cfoutput query="yourQuery" group="FoodCategoryName">
      <!--- display header once -->
      #FoodCategoryName#<br><br>
      <cfoutput>
         <!--- display all foods --->
          #FoodName#<br>
      </cfoutput>
  </cfoutput>
```