# Linking Remarks and Comments with Javascript and ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, ms-access, coldfusion

Using ColdFusion, Access and Javascript, I have been able to set up a program that when you touch a button it gives you a photo. Then I have used the JOIN method to link two worksheets in the database. Now what I am trying to do is work the JOIN into the program so that when I click a Image it shows the Remarks that are associated with the Image through the Image_id. Can someone help me with displaying the remarks associated with each Image?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <cfquery datasource="AccessTest" name="qTest">
        SELECT Account, Image, Image_ID
        FROM PictureDB
    </cfquery>


            <cfquery datasource="AccessTest" NAME=qtest2>
                            SELECT *
                 FROM CommentsDB AS C 
                 INNER JOIN PictureDB AS P
    ON C.Image_ID = P.Image_ID
</cfquery>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"> </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var images = {

    <cfloop query="qTest">
    "<cfoutput>#qTest.Image_ID#</cfoutput>": "<cfoutput>#qTest.Image#</cfoutput>",
    </cfloop>
    };

    $("button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var src = images[id];

        $("#theImage").attr("src", src).removeClass("hide");

    });

});
</script>

<div id="div1">
    <h2>Display Image</h2>
</div>

    <cfoutput query="qTest">
        <button data-id="#qTest.Image_ID#">#qTest.Account#  </button>
    </cfoutput> 
    <img id="theImage" class="hide">
</html>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

New code after I made the changes.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <cfquery datasource="AccessTest" name="qTest">
        SELECT Account, Image, Image_ID
        FROM PictureDB
    </cfquery>

<cfquery datasource="AccessTest" NAME=qtest2>
        SELECT *
        FROM CommentsDB AS C 
        INNER JOIN PictureDB AS P
        ON C.Image_ID = P.Image_ID
    </cfquery>





 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"> </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var images = {
    <cfloop query="qTest">
    "<cfoutput>#qTest.Image_ID#</cfoutput>": "<cfoutput>#qTest.Image#</cfoutput>",
    </cfloop>
    };

    var descs= {
    <cfloop query="qtest2">
    "<cfoutput>#qtest2.Image_ID#</cfoutput>": "<cfoutput>#qtest2.Remarks#</cfoutput>",
    </cfloop>
};

    $("button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var src = images[id];
        var desc = descs[id];

        $("#theImage").attr("src", src).removeClass("hide");
        $("#theDescription").html(desc).removeClass("hide");
    });

});
</script>



<body>
<div id="div1">
    <h2>Display Image</h2>
</div>

    <cfoutput query="qTest">
        <button data-id="#qTest.Image_ID#">#qTest.Account#  </button>
    </cfoutput> 

    <img id="theImage" class="hide">
    <div id="theDescription" class="hide">




</html>

</body>
```

"View Source Code" Code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>






 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"> </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var images = {

    "1": "Test1.png#Test1.png#",

    "2": "Test2.png#Test2.png#",

    "3": "Test3.png#Test3.png#",

    "4": "Test4.png#Test4.png#",

    "5": "Test5.png#Test5.png#",

    "6": "Test6.png#Test6.png#",

    };

    var descs= {

    "5": "Test5",

    "6": "Test6",

    "1": "B Test",

    "1": "A Test",

    "2": "Test2",

    "3": "Test3",

    "4": "Test4",

};

    $("button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var src = images[id];
        var desc = descs[id];

        $("#theImage").attr("src", src).removeClass("hide");
        $("#theDescription").html(desc).removeClass("hide");
    });

});
</script>



<body>
<div id="div1">
    <h2>Display Image</h2>
</div>


        <button data-id="1">Dunblane  </button>

        <button data-id="2">Main Campus  </button>

        <button data-id="3">Law School  </button>

        <button data-id="4">New Mexico Ave  </button>

        <button data-id="5">Soccer Field  </button>

        <button data-id="6">Capital Hall  </button>


    <img id="theImage" class="hide">
    <div id="theDescription" class="hide">




</html>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just extend what you've already got to include the descriptions too.  There are better ways to do this (I'd rather have one array of structs, and one query instead of two), but this is probably the simplest to implement based on your current code without rewriting it all.

Also note that instead of using `<cfloop query..>` I've used `<cfoutput query...>` which saves you then having to wrap all our content with cfoutput inside the loop.

```
var descs= {
    <cfoutput query="qtest2">
    "#qtest2.Image_ID#": "#qtest2.Remarks#",
    </cfoutput>
};

var src = images[id];
var desc = descs[id];

$("#theImage").attr("src", src).removeClass("hide");
$("#theDescription").html(desc).removeClass("hide");

<img id="theImage" class="hide">
<div id="theDescription" class="hide"></div>
```

---

Updated answer: 
I'd use one query to get all the images and remarks at the same time.  It makes your javascript a bit more complicated, and this isn't ideal, but this approach should work.  (the trailing commas on the last items in your javascript arrays and structures will throw an error in IE, but I leave it as an exercise for yourself to work out how you can use a counter to determine if you need to add a comma or not).

Then we can use grouped output, so we get all the remarks.  I've put them here as an array, but it could just be a string as well.

```
<cfquery datasource="AccessTest" name="qTest">
    SELECT P.Account, P.Image, P.Image_ID, C.Remarks
    FROM PictureDB AS P
    INNER JOIN CommentsDB AS C
    ON C.Image_ID = P.Image_ID
    ORDER BY P.Image_ID
</cfquery>

var images = {
    <cfoutput query="qTest" group="Image_ID">
        "#qTest.Image_ID#": {
            "image": "#qTest.Image#",
            "remarks": [
            <cfoutput>
                "#qTest.Remarks#",
            </cfoutput>
            ]
        },
    </cfoutput>
};

$("button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var src = images[id].image;
    var desc = images[id].remarks.toString();

    $("#theImage").attr("src", src).removeClass("hide");
    $("#theDescription").html(desc).removeClass("hide");
});
```

Comment: One more question. Do you know why only the first Remarks linked to the image are showing up?

Comment: Can you show us the generated javascript (i.e. view source on your page, not the CFML code)

Comment: I did a test and made the Remarks. "B Test" under the first button, "Dunblane." This showed up. Then when I added "A Test." It replaced "B Test". It seems to only show  the first one accounting for Alphabetical Order.

Comment: ah so you have two remarks for image with ID 1... what do you want to do in that case; show them both?

Comment: Side note, rather than building your own JSON string, I would recommend using `serializeJSON` instead. It has some quirks, but it should be fine for this case.

Comment: This is showing the Remarks perfectly but now there are extra buttons.

Comment: <cfoutput query="qTest" group="Account">
        <button data-id="#qTest.Image_ID#">#qTest.Account# </button>
    </cfoutput>..... using group solves  this. Thanks.

Comment: Word of warning - if you're going to group the output on the Account column, you should make sure and include that in the ORDER BY of your query (it doesn't have to be the first column ordered on)

Comment: @duncan - Actually the grouped column *must* be the first. Otherwise, there is no guarantee it will work as expected. It *might*, by coincidence or based on the relationships of the data, but really it is not guaranteed unless you first sort the results by the same columns you are "group"ing.

Comment: @Leigh - I've always heard that the order of the columns doesn't matter, as long as it's in the ORDER BY somewhere.  What if you have multiple grouped output - what order should the columns be in this case?  Can you write something up that demonstrates your point (I don't disbelieve you)?

Comment: @duncan - You can test it yourself with a basic [category/detail scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18524431/104223). Just sort the results by detail first, *then* category and see what happens. The `group` feature does not perform any special magic. It simply spits out the current value in the `group` column whenever it changes. So if you do not pre-sort the results by that column, to ensure same values are grouped together, you will get unexpected results.

Comment: (darn character limit ..) *RE:multiple grouped output* Same rules apply. You must first sort by the `group` columns - in the same order as your `group` statements. After that, you can sort by whatever columns you want.